# Lodash: How to remove item or nested item from array using an id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "denuzi",
        "sub":
        [
            {"id": "s4p58o"},
            {"id": "xzbqi"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "4rcodm",
        "sub": [],
    }
]
```

What I am trying to do is remove an item from the array or from a nested array using a provided id.

e.g. if `denuzi` is provided then the entire first object is removed; if `s4p58o` is provided just that object from the first objects sub array is removed.

I know that I can remove an entire object with the following code:

```
_.remove(this.items, function(item) {
    return item.id !== id;
});
```

But I am not sure how to make a check to remove a sub item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by checking the `id` or call again for `sub`. Exit if found.

```js
function remove(array, id) {
    return array.some((o, i, a) => o.id === id
        ? a.splice(i, 1)
        : remove(o.sub || [], id)
    );
}

var array = [{ id: "denuzi", sub: [{ id: "s4p58o" }, { id: "xzbqi" }] }, { id: "4rcodm", sub: [] }];

remove(array, 's4p58o');
console.log(array);

remove(array, 'denuzi');
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var list = [
    {
        "id": "denuzi",
        "sub":
        [
            {"id": "s4p58o"},
            {"id": "xzbqi"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "4rcodm",
        "sub": [],
    }
]

const result = list.filter(a => a.id !== 'denuzi');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for nested structure, for example, you `s4p58o` can't be removed with your solution.